# Values in a .ini file

Tags: pyramid, ini

I have a pyramid app and am looking at the .ini file. What is the difference between using `paypal.client_id` -v- `paypal_client_id` Does the `.` signify something specific, for example that reload is a part of pyramid?

If I have a lot of configurations regarding vehicles for example should I use `vehicles.limit` or `vehicles_limit`?

```
[app:main]
use = egg:vehiclesvc

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en

paypal.client_id = 1412431231
paypal.secret_key = asdasdasdasd
```

or

```
[app:main]
use = egg:vehiclesvc

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en

paypal_client_id = 1412431231
paypal_secret_key = asdasdasdasd
```

Comment: Please provide an actual example of usage by editing your answer. In the meantime, read [Environment Variables and `.ini` File Settings](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html).

Comment: @StevePiercy thanks - I have updated the question with a better example of what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see an instance of either `pyramid.reload` -v- `pyramid_reload` in your `.ini` file. Nonetheless, there are certain setting names that are reserved for Pyramid use, as documented in [Environment Variables and `.ini` File Settings](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html).

For those setting names reserved by Pyramid, `pyramid.<setting_name>` and `<setting_name>` are equivalent.

All other setting names, including those you define, may be used elsewhere in configuring your application. Again see the referenced linked documentation for details.

See also ConfigParser's documentation on [Supported INI File Structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure).

> A configuration file consists of sections, each led by a `[section]` header, followed by key/value entries separated by a specific string (`=` or `:` by default).

Finally to answer you explicit question, `pyramid.reload` -v- `pyramid_reload` would be both distinct and not reserved by Pyramid. Similarly `vehicles.limit` and `vehicles_limit` would be both distinct key names and not reserved by Pyramid. By convention it is helpful to use `<python_package>.` to designate a Python package where the key name is used.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe my question wasn't clear. I want to have a PayPal client ID and PayPal secret key in my settings. Should I be doing `paypal.client` and `paypal.secret` or `paypal_client` and `paypal_secret` Does it make a difference if I use `.` instead of `_`?

Comment: It's a personal preference on how to name the keys, and makes no difference whether you use `.`, `_`, or any other character except those that ConfigParser interprets as special, such as `%`, `#`, or `;`. On a side note, for security purposes, I recommend not putting the actual value of secrets in your code. Key names are OK, but values that are secrets should be kept secret and loaded as environment variables.